# DLL being overwritten by older version in Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a Web Application in Visual Studio 2012 using HtmlAgilityPack. My project references the 1.4.0.0 version of the dll in the application's bin folder. Previously it used 1.3.0.0

The application works, but about once a day the dll in the bin folder is overwritten replacing version 1.4.0.0 with 1.3.0.0. I've already checked the GAC and deleted my ASP.NET temp folders the first time this happened. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Make it readonly with attrib.exe so it cannot be deleted.  Something ought to go bang! when it happens again.  Giving the junior team members a day off is a popular way to eliminate a possibility.

Comment: This seems like a pretty decent avenue to try. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Read only doesn't seem to effect it. I believe one of the people working on the project is committing project files referencing the old version of the DLL. This, coupled with the fact that I regularly run other apps that use 1.3 makes me believe IIS is pulling 1.3 out of the asp cache.

Comment: Do you have several projects in one solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need also delete the 1.3.0.0 dll from you solution's reference list from Solution Explorer.

Comment: The 1.3.0.0 reference was deleted when we updated to version 1.4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The older .dll is apparently being referenced from somewhere within your solution. I would open the project file(s) in an editor and look for any references to older versions there.

If none are found, my guess would be that some other library or component you are relying on is referencing the old version of the .dll (are you using any third party libraries?). If you don't have the source for these, then perhaps you can decompile them using [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) or some similar tool. Then you can at least check the references within the dll's your using, and confirm or rule it out as the source of your problem (no pun intented ^^).

Oh, and one more thing - maybe obvious, but have you set `Specific version = true` for the reference?

Comment: `Specific version = true` is indeed set and the program fails because it cannot load that version (as it was overwritten by 1.3).

Our 3rd-party libraries were all updated to versions that used 1.4 when we made to the move to 1.4.

A full text search of our project files for the phrase "HtmlAgilityPack" only yield correct references to version 1.4.0.0.

Comment: We also added a version redirect to our Web.config.